# I want to join variables (columns) from two different files with a matching column using join - problems with output

Tags: linux, output, join

Good day.  I am new to linux and really hope someone can help me.

I have two files:

File 1 : Column1=id_nr;  Column2=snp_info

[image: Column1=id_nr; Column2=snp_info]

File 2 : Column1=id_nr;  Column2=recoded_id_nr

[image: Column1=id_nr; Column2=recoded_id_nr]

I want to join the two files so that I end up with a file with Column1=recoded_id_nr and Column2=snp_info for animals (id_nr) present in File 1 and File 2.  The id_nr are the matching variable and both files are sorted on it.

In linux I used the various forms of the join function, but get the same as the common one below:

```
join file1 file2
```

Result:

[image]

It gives the correct animals that are present in both files, but the problem is with the first column.  The first integer is the correct recoded_id_nr, but it is fused (concatenated), without any space, with the last 8 digits of the id_nr of the 3 animals that are present in both files. Thus, it cuts of the first 2 digits of the id_nr and replace it with the recoded_id_nr.  The second column (snp_info) is fine.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.
Michiel

Comment: Please replace images by real text so we can copy to our editors and reply.

Comment: When text ends up displaced after joining file contents, my first guess is that one or both input files has Windows (CRLF) line endings. See for example [ed does not join lines with ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/707468/ed-does-not-join-lines-with-ascii-text-with-crlf-lf-line-terminators) and [How to test whether a file uses CRLF or LF without modifying it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79702/how-to-test-whether-a-file-uses-crlf-or-lf-without-modifying-it)

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you very much.  Windows line endings was indeed the problem and something I was not even aware of.  I corrected it with sed -i.bak -E 's/[[:space:]]+$//' file.txt and it worked.  The join is now successful.